# Why String is returning Junk values

Tags: c++, arrays, string, queue

Here I am using Data Structure Queues to change cards places using strings. User picks the top card than put it at last of the deck. The problem is that I need to return updated string to main. What it is returning is junk Values. I also tried to copy the string array and than returning that arraybut didn't work. Can anyone help?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
string CommunityChest(string Cards[]){
    struct Que{
     string cards[6];
     int front =0;
     int back=-1;
    }ComQ;
    string temp;

    for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
    {//Enqueue(Cards)
        ComQ.back++;
        if(ComQ.back<=5)
        {
            ComQ.cards[ComQ.back]=Cards[i];
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Overflow";
        }
    }
    //Display
    for(int i=ComQ.front; i<=ComQ.back; i++)
    {
        cout<<ComQ.cards[i]<<endl;
    }
    //Del()
    if(ComQ.front>=0)
    {
        temp=ComQ.cards[ComQ.front];
        ComQ.front++;
    }
    cout<<endl<<"Pick the top Card"<<endl;
    cout<<temp<<endl;
    //EnQ the picked card
    ComQ.back++;
    if(ComQ.back<=5)
        {
            ComQ.cards[ComQ.back]=temp;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Overflow";
        }
        cout<<endl<<"After Inserting top card:"<<endl;
        //Display
        string newQ1[5];
    for (int i=ComQ.front; i<=ComQ.back; i++)    //Making an alternate array to copy Comq.cards array data
    {
        newQ1[i]=ComQ.cards[i];            
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        return newQ1[i];          //trying to return string array
        //cout<< newQ1<<endl;
    }

}
int main(){

string cards[5]{ "1 Advance ........",
                 "2. It is your ...........",
                 "3. You have won .............",//Cards as strings
                 "4. From sale of..............",
                 "5. Pay Hospital............"};
       string newQ1=CommunityChest(cards);
       for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
       cout << newQ1[i] << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You make some very basic mistakes in your code, some which suggest to me that you have skipped some important parts of your learning material when it comes to arrays and how they work. First of all, you can't really return a C-style array like `newQ1`. Secondly, your loop to return the array returns only a single element from the array. There are other things that just looks wrong or suspect.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with this code as mentioned in the comments, you are trying to do a return in a loop, this may look okay but it's wrong since a return can get you out of the function. But it seems like you want to return an array of strings.

A fix for this function would be like this:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string* CommunityChest(std::string Cards[]) {
    struct Que {
        std::string cards[6];
        int front = 0;
        int back = -1;
    } ComQ;
    std::string temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // Enqueue(Cards)
        ComQ.back++;
        if (ComQ.back <= 5) {
            ComQ.cards[ComQ.back] = Cards[i];
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Overflow";
        }
    }
    // Display
    for (int i = ComQ.front; i <= ComQ.back; i++) {
        std::cout << ComQ.cards[i] << std::endl;
    }
    // Del()
    if (ComQ.front >= 0) {
        temp = ComQ.cards[ComQ.front];
        ComQ.front++;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl
         << "Pick the top Card" << std::endl;
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    // EnQ the picked card
    ComQ.back++;
    if (ComQ.back <= 5) {
        ComQ.cards[ComQ.back] = temp;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Overflow";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl
         << "After Inserting top card:" << std::endl;
    // Display
    // Creating a dynamic array to store the values
    std::string* newQ1 = new std::string[5];
    for (int i = ComQ.front, j = 0; i <= ComQ.back && j < 5; i++, j++) {// Making an alternate array to copy Comq.cards array data
        newQ1[j] = ComQ.cards[i];
    }
    return newQ1; // Returning the dynamic array
}
int main()
{
    std::string cards[5]{
        "1 Advance ........",
        "2. It is your ...........",
        "3. You have won .............", // Cards as strings
        "4. From sale of..............",
        "5. Pay Hospital............"
    };
    std::string* newQ1 = CommunityChest(cards);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << newQ1[i] << std::endl;
    }
    delete[] newQ1; // Deleting the array
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be:

```
1 Advance ........
2. It is your ...........
3. You have won .............
4. From sale of..............
5. Pay Hospital............

Pick the top Card
1 Advance ........

After Inserting top card:
2. It is your ...........
3. You have won .............
4. From sale of..............
5. Pay Hospital............
1 Advance ........
```

In this fix, I'm returning a dynamically allocated array of strings because a static array will be destroyed once the scope ends, it would be better sometimes to use other ways to allocate memory such as `std::unique_ptr<>` or `std::shared_ptr<>`, but I'd suggest you learn how to do it yourself first then use those when needed.

EDIT:
You can also return an `std::array<>`, I suggest you to read about it as C-Style arrays cannot be returned in you way that you tried and can't be returned without using dynamic allocation, so an `std::array<>` can be a good replacement over std::string* in this case